# selecting values from a reference table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a `users` table and have roles such as `admin|manager|employee` which are represented in reference table called `reference`.

user table - `id|first_name|last_name|type|status`

reference table - `id|table|type|key|value`

Now the reference table contains integer key that match values so `user.type` has `0-admin,1-manager,2-employee` which looks something like this

```
table:user
type:type
key:0
value:admin
```

My problem is when I have to values in a table which need to access the reference table.

```
table:user
type:status
key:0
value:enabled
```

Question: How can I access two reference table values in one statement?

//STATEMENT

```
SELECT a.id,a.first_name,a.last_name,b.value as user_type,b.value as user_status
FROM user AS a 
JOIN reference as b 
ON 'user'=b.table AND 'type'=b.type AND a.type = b.value AND a.status = b.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to the reference table twice (or three times, or four times...). Just give it two different aliases:

```
SELECT a.id,a.first_name,a.last_name,b.value as user_type,b.value AS user_type, b2.value as user_status
FROM user AS a 
JOIN reference AS b 
ON 'user'=b.table AND 'type'=b.type AND a.type = b.value 
JOIN reference AS b2
ON 'user'=b2.table AND 'status'=b2.type AND a.status = b2.value
```

Unless I'm mis-interpreting your requirements, I believe the above is what you are seeking.

Comment: close, basically what I had though both the `user_type` and `user_status` will be filled with the same values `admin|manger|employee` when `user_status` should only contain `enabled|disabled`

Comment: Ook I got just had to change the `b.value` to `b2.value` and works great!

Comment: Ah, right, I should have added b2.value to the SELECT clause. Anyway, glad it works well for you!

Comment: Do you know why it returns multiple results?

Comment: I would assume it is because you have multiple users who fulfill the JOIN criteria. (Currently, your JOIN criteria is just bringing in 'type'-type and 'status'-type reference tables for all users, if I understand your schema correctly.) If you wanted to limit the users returned to, you would need to modify the JOINs to be more selective (or, alternatively, add in a WHERE clause).